# Token Ring Number of nodes in MAU

Tags: networking, network-protocols

why the token ring has limitation of 260 nodes per MAU using STP cables?
 How the number of nodes per MAU is calculated?

I know we can use more than 260, but why IEEE-802.5 is Standardized it to 260 or 250?

Comment: Is this for a history class?

Comment: Could you help us understand why this really matters to you in 2014?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, ugh. Token Ring. My first employer, back in the late 90s, did a bunch of contract work for a manufacturing company and some hospitals that used Token Ring. I've slung more STP cables and plugged-in more of those funky "genderless" IBM connector cables than I'd like to remember.

First of all, you're mixing-up your terminology. Each Multi-station Access Unit (MAU or MSAU) has eight ports for connection of nodes, and a "ring in" and "ring out" port to connect to other MAUs. The total number of MAUs in a ring using STP cable can be 33.

Regarding the limit of 250 (in IEEE 802.5) or 260 (in IBM Token Ring) nodes on the ring, the best reference I can find is [near the bottom of page 103 of *Network Analysis and Troubleshooting* in section 3.6.4](http://books.google.com/books?id=dCcNjsfj-CwC&lpg=PA103&ots=rmHUKsL21i&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q&f=false), which states:

> There are problems ... with jitter. Jitter occurs when the signaling becomes distorted ...  It is primarily for this reason that Token Rings are limited to 250 nodes.

Jitter causes a shift in the timing of pulses in a digital signal. [This page has a nice graphical representation of the effects of jitter on a digital signal.](http://www.maznets.com/tech/jitter.htm) Token Ring is particularly susceptible to jitter because each node in a Token Ring network repeats the signal it receives from the previous node in the ring.

The Token Ring protocol feels like a case of over-engineering. Ethernet networks are "plug and play" compared to Token Ring's [nasty formulas and tables](http://www.intel.com/support/tokenexpress/sb/cs-012004.htm) accounting for cable lengths, number of stations, number of MAUs, etc. When you bring the ugly stuff like beaconing, ring error monitors, etc, into it then it really gets ugly. I remember quite a few times, in those few years that I worked around Token Ring, when the mysterious "network guys" with their equally mysterious "sniffer" would have to come in and isolate faults in cabling, NICs, or bad MAUs (or occasionally the silly barnyard-theme named CAU and LAM devices).

I'm glad Token Ring is dead. Good riddance.

Comment: That sniffer is what they used to look for the token when it fell out.

Comment: +1 for *"Good riddance"*